# C# FileStream, file is larger than last Position

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm attempting to write to a `FileStream`.  After the last write, I see `stream.Position` is `11,247,160`.  After this check, all there is is a `Flush`, `Close`, and then the using automatically disposes of the `FileStream`.  This is also the value of `Position` when it hits the line containing the `Close` call.  However, when I look at the file in explorer, the size is 12,847,148 bytes, or 1.5MB larger.  When I read back the data, there's a bunch of gibberish data at the end.  Has anyone seen this before?

Thank you.

Comment: Post the code you have.

Comment: Are you truncating the file? If not, you may be overwriting old data and leaving old data at the end.

Comment: VisualMelon, you got it.  I was using File.OpenWrite.  When I switch to File.Open with FileMode.Create, it works correctly.  If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: @Nikhil It would be better for you to write your own answer to this one, I should think, as you can detail exactly what was going wrong (this will be more helpful to people who run into the same issue in the future)

Comment: You can also call [SetLength()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.setlength.aspx) against your FileStream and pass it a length of 0 (zero) before writing out the new contents.  "If the given value is less than the current length of the stream, the stream is truncated."